# How to create working like button in flask and sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2, web-development-server

I am trying to create a social network using flask and sqlite3. I had created almost all the main things like post, edit post, delete post. But I also want to add the like button for every post. I had created like number(How many like this post got) and like button and it is working fine but If you like my post for the first time and again login your account then you can again like that post which you had already liked by your account.

I had an idea to save who liked my post but i don't know how to implement that exact code in my webapp.I am using sqlite3 so I am not finding any solution for this issue. I had found exactly same question for mysql or any other database but I had not for sqlite3.

Ok here is my idea,
I had already mentioned that I am using sqlite3 so I had created table like this:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect('data/detailpost.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE postdetail(
                                name text,
                                address text,
                                post text,
                                post_date text,
                                secretcode text,
                                mainname text,
                                likes integer,
                                likers text)""")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

and If someone click like button(In template) then that will come in this part of back-end where I am getting liker mainname and oid number of that post.And this is the same back-end code which increase the like of the post. Like this

```
@app.route('/social/post/like',methods=['POST'])
def likedofsocial():
    if request.method=='POST':
        oid=request.form['oid']
        mainusernameofliker=request.form['username']
        conn=sqlite3.connect('data/detailpost.db')
        c=conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT *,oid FROM postdetail WHERE oid="+oid)
        alldata=c.fetchall()
        for rec in alldata:
            c.execute("""UPDATE postdetail SET 
                name=:name,
                address=:address,
                post=:post,
                post_date=:datee,
                secretcode=:secret,
                mainname=:mainname,
                likes=:likes
                likers=:likers
                WHERE oid=:num""",
                {
                    'name':rec[0],
                    'address':rec[1],
                    'post':rec[2],
                    'datee':rec[3],
                    'secret':rec[4],
                    'mainname':rec[5],
                    'likes':(int(rec[6]+1)),
                    'likers':mainusernameofliker,
                    'num':oid,
                })       
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            .....
```

Here in this above part I don't know how to save multiple mainusernameofliker inside `likers` beacause there will not be only one person who likes my posts.

Now I have only idea for front-end I had not tried any of the code which is mentioned below!! I just think following code could works fine

"For front-end check that likers data and

```
(% if (your mainusername is in that likers data ) %)

  then show already liked(Liked) or disable like button

(% else (your username is not in that likers data) %)

  then that show like or make clickable like button".

(% endif %)
```

Probably, I could get help as soon as possible and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main question is that how to store the multiple users who would like the post. It is very simple, you just need to create one more table maybe called `postlikers`. This table will reference primary keys of `user` and `postdetail`. Basically a many-to-many relationship between `user` and `postdetail` tables.

I will show you an example that how you can define the tables below:

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect('detailpost.db')
c=conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name text)
          """)

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postdetail(
                                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                name text,
                                address text,
                                post text,
                                post_date text,
                                secretcode text,
                                mainname text,
                                likes integer DEFAULT 0
                                )""")
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postlikers(
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     post_id INTEGER,
     user_id INTEGER,
     FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES postdetail(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
            )
          """)
conn.commit()
conn.close()  

# Add data

user_data = [('Carl'), ('Mel'), ('Bobby')]
post_data = [('first_post', 'whajjne', 'I love everything', 'dfweffwwffefe', 'secret', 'Carl', 0),
             ('second_post', 'whajjne', 'I love everything', 'dfweffwwffefe', 'secret', 'Mel', 0)]
conn=sqlite3.connect('detailpost.db')
c=conn.cursor()
for user in user_data:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (?);', (user,))
for post in post_data:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO postdetail (name, address, post, post_date, secretcode, mainname,likes ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?, ?);', post)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: I would prefer StackOverflow if you can question here....